# SQLite select gives value above limit in where clause

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with some performance data. I want to query some data from a table called timings that fulfills some constraints:

1. The number of processors should be 32. The corresponding column is called nProcs
2. The number of degrees of freedom in a given domain should not be above 4096. The column is called DofPEPV.

I'm interested in distinct entries for DofPEPV. So my query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DofPEPV FROM timings WHERE nProcs='32' AND DofPEPV<='4096'
```

The query is executed in python:

```
sqlcon = sqlite3.connect('database.file')
selquery = 'SELECT DISTINCT DofPEPV FROM timings WHERE nProcs=\'32\' AND DofPEPV<=\'4096\''
for val in sqlcon.execute(selquery):
    print(val)
```

Works like a charm except that there are also values written that are above 4096, e.g. 29791. How can this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT DofPEPV FROM timings WHERE nProcs='32' AND DofPEPV<='4096'
```

is the 4096 is string? if this is integer erase the quot..instead use this

`SELECT DISTINCT DofPEPV FROM timings WHERE nProcs=32 AND DofPEPV<=4096`

Comment: Please see the comment on jarlh answer. He answered first, so I marked his answer as solution.

Comment: i answered first..look at my time.. i answer 9.37 but jarlh answered 9.38

Answer (score 3):

You are not comparing integer values here, you are comparing string values.

What you want to do is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DofPEPV FROM timings WHERE nProcs= 32  AND DofPEPV<= 4096;
```

Comment: Actually I am comparing string values. And this is the problem. The data is not converted into integers when read into the database. I totally missed that.